# Laravel not registering a new command

Tags: php, laravel

I am  using laravel 5.5 and trying to create a new command. This has worked well in 5.4 but now it won't register at all.

First I create the command:

```
php artisan make:command heloworl
```

And I get something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class heloworl extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'Hello:World';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        echo "hello world";
    }
}
```

Now I try `php artisan hello:world` and it says that the  command does not exist at all.

I also tried just `php artisan` to get a list of commands and it is not there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to `app\Console\Kernel.php` to the `protected $commands` array.

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{

    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands
        = [
        //fully qualified namespace to class goes here
        ];

}
```

Comment: I can't believe Laravel won't do this automaticly.

Comment: it does load them automatically in **5.5** if they are in the correct place

Comment: @prgrm [Oh, but it can](http://sergeyzhuk.me/2016/08/17/laravel-console-commands/). But this is also already done in Laravel 5.5

Comment: @prgrm Just do a `composer dumpautoload` probably.

Answer (score 3):

I had a Laravel 5.2 project that I upgraded to 5.5, and for me it wasn't loading them automatically for some reason, even though I had the command classes in the right place.

Turns out I had to modify `app/Console/Kernel.php`, adding the following line to the top of the `commands` method:

```
$this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');
```

After this I was able to use my commands properly, and I didn't have to add each of them to the `$commands` array.

Comment: It is mentioned in the [Laravel 5.5 Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade).

Comment: @Namoshek In my case I didn't use commands before the upgrade took place, so I probably skipped that section back then.